# More user friendly search box in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented searchbox using `jQuery`. Here is the code which sends search term and
after that I receive `Json` which I use to make list of matched searched items.

The problem is that on each `keyup` I delete all matched items :

```
    $("#realPlaceForSearchItems").html("");
```

because if I don't  that I get duplications when searching for product if I enter "**pro**" and then type "**d**". (I am appending  list items  to the list)  Is it possible to achieve that I somehow just delete elements that do not match "**prod**" (which previously matched "**pro**" ofcourse) and that elements that match prod stay untouched after typing "**d**".

```
 $("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $('#realPlaceForSearchItems').show();
    $("#realPlaceForSearchItems").html("");
    var seachedTerm=$this.val();

    if ($this.val().length> 2)
    {

        $("#realPlaceForSearchItems").html("");
        $('#realPlaceForSearchItems').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ROOT + "Filter/Search/",
            data: {term: $this.val()},
            success: function (data)
            {

                var Link = $("#searchTemplate>li>a");
                var placeForProductId=$("#searchTemplate>li>a>input");
                var placeForPicture = $("#searchTemplate>li>a>div>img");
                var placeForProductName = $("#searchTemplate>li>a>div>div");
                var placeForPrice= $("#searchTemplate>li>a>div>span");

                $.each(data.productsWereSeached, function () {

                    console.log("sddsd", data.totalrows);
                    var imagesFolder="/Content/images/";
                    var pathToProduct="/ProductDetails/Index/"
                    var slash = "/";

                    Link.attr("href", pathToProduct + this.Id);
                    placeForProductId.val(this.Id);
                    if (this && this.Picture) //for the case there is no any picture there would be error cant read propery or undefined
                        placeForPicture.attr("src", imagesFolder + this.Id + slash + this.Picture.FileName);
                    else
                        placeForPicture.attr("src", "");
                    placeForProductName.html(this.Name);
                    placeForPrice.html((parseFloat(this.Price) / 100.0).toString() + " kn");

                    $listItem = $("#searchTemplate").html();
                    $("#realPlaceForSearchItems").append($listItem);

                });
                $("#nOfMatchedProducts").val(data.totalrows);
                if (data.totalrows > 2)
                {
                    var searchurl="/Search/ShowMoreSearched?term="
                    $showMoreItem = $("#showMoreItem").html();
                    $("#showMoreItem>li>a").attr("href",searchurl+seachedTerm);
                    $("#realPlaceForSearchItems").append($showMoreItem);
                }


            },
            failure: function ()
            {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sending a request on every keystroke seems awfully chatty.  Does this search have to be as-you-type or can you just provide the user with a button to click (or they could just press return) to actually run the search?  If you really want an as-you-type search then I recommend putting in a delay of about half a second, managed outside of the keyup event.  The search should only happen after the delay, and the keyup event should reset the delay.  (I'm being vague because I don't have a concrete example handy.)  That way the user can finish typing before the search happens.

Comment: @David Google sends an AJAX request for every key pressed when searching :)

Comment: Why not use jQuery AutoComplete? Then you can focus on the more interesting parts of your program that others haven't solved before.

Comment: Because, I want my own implementation, my own design that matches design of the rest of page. You can see search items have picture etc.

Comment: @imperator that's not something jQuery's AutoComplete can't do.

Comment: My project is not to big, just some shopping site, and as I am begginer I want to learn as more as possible. Now understand? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $.each(data.productsWereSeached, function () {
    if($('a[href="'+pathToProduct + this.Id+'"]').length == 0) {
            console.log("sddsd", data.totalrows);
            var imagesFolder="/Content/images/";
            var pathToProduct="/ProductDetails/Index/"
            var slash = "/";

            Link.attr("href", pathToProduct + this.Id);
            placeForProductId.val(this.Id);
            if (this && this.Picture) //for the case there is no any picture there would be error cant read propery or undefined
                placeForPicture.attr("src", imagesFolder + this.Id + slash + this.Picture.FileName);
            else
                placeForPicture.attr("src", "");
            placeForProductName.html(this.Name);
            placeForPrice.html((parseFloat(this.Price) / 100.0).toString() + " kn");

            $listItem = $("#searchTemplate").html();
            $("#realPlaceForSearchItems").append($listItem);
     }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

*Psst... I'm assuming you also want to limit calls to the server and that your search result list is not wildly huge!*

So!  Benefit to your current approach is you don't have to manage/compare any existing data set.  This makes things easier when a search for "pro" changes to a search for "cro" or any other change that makes the previous AJAX call irrelevant.  But, like you said, it leaves you with this *clear then re-add items* inefficiency when you search for "prod" after "pro".

Idea:

1. Store the most recent AJAX call criteria in a global.
2. If new search value includes the latest AJAX search value, filter/hide items in the existing data set which do not match the new criteria.  Do not perform a new search.
3. If new value does not include the latest AJAX search value: clear current data set, update AJAX search value, execute new AJAX call

Comment: Even if you do not want to limit calls to the server, you'll still hit the same issue when the previous search is not relevant to the new search.  Remember to test for it!

Comment: No! I get only 4 result. I used Take(4) in my controller action. I don't want limit anything. I just don't want to get "flashing" searchbox.

Comment: Store the Id of current values in a simple array.  When new results come in, compare an item id against the simple array.  If NEW, append item and append value to array.  Else, do nothing.

Comment: Last guess... your "flashing" searchbox happens due to it being empty for a fraction of a second.  Options:

1) build new results as new LI dom elements and replace the existing LI search result elements.  Do this instead of clearing/adding new ones.  OR 
2) add static a static height to your container of search items to prevent it from "flashing" or going to it's minimum empty height when there's no content inside.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the **index** from $.each (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) into your function, then use it to select the search result you will **replaceWith** (http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) the element you just built.  In using this method, your four LI elements within the search results UL must exist before a search.keyup is executed.

Do this by changing two lines...

```
$.each(data.productsWereSeached, function (index) {

    ... all of the existing code in the loop stays the same except ... 

    $("#realPlaceForSearchItems LI:eq(" + index + ")").replaceWith($listItem);
});
```